# kubernetes pending pod priority

Tags: kubernetes, preemption

I have the following pods on my kubernetes (1.18.3) cluster:

```
NAME      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod1      1/1     Running   0          14m
pod2      1/1     Running   0          14m
pod3      0/1     Pending   0          14m
pod4      0/1     Pending   0          14m
```

pod3 and pod4 cannot start because the node has capacity for 2 pods only. When pod1 finishes and quits, then the scheduler picks either pod3 or pod4 and starts it. So far so good.

However, I also have a high priority pod (hpod) that I'd like to start before pod3 or pod4 when either of the running pods finishes and quits.

So I created a priorityclass can be found in the kubernetes docs:

```
kind: PriorityClass
metadata:
  name: high-priority-no-preemption
value: 1000000
preemptionPolicy: Never
globalDefault: false
description: "This priority class should be used for XYZ service pods only."
```

I've created the following pod yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hpod
  labels:
    app: hpod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: hpod
    image: ...
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: "500m"
        memory: "500Mi"
      limits:
        cpu: "500m"
        memory: "500Mi"
  priorityClassName: high-priority-no-preemption
```

Now the problem is that when I start the high prio pod with kubectl apply -f hpod.yaml, then the scheduler terminates a running pod to allow the high priority pod to start despite I've set 'preemptionPolicy: Never'.

The expected behaviour would be to postpone starting hpod until a currently running pod finishes. And when it does, then let hpod start before pod3 or pod4.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you enagle `NonPreemptingPriority` futuregate? What apiVersion did you use in PriorityClass?

Comment: No, I overlooked this condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Prerequisites:**

This solution was tested on Kubernetes `v1.18.3`, docker 19.03 and Ubuntu 18.
Also text editor is required (i.e. `sudo apt-get install vim`).

In Kubernetes documentation under [How to disable preemption](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/#how-to-disable-preemption) you can find **Note**:

> Note: In Kubernetes `1.15` and later, if the feature `NonPreemptingPriority` is `enabled`, `PriorityClasses` have the option to set `preemptionPolicy: Never`. This will prevent pods of that `PriorityClass` from preempting other pods.

Also under [Non-preempting PriorityClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/#non-preempting-priority-class) you have information:

> The use of the PreemptionPolicy field requires the `NonPreemptingPriority` feature gate to be `enabled`.

Later if you will check thoses [Feature Gates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/) info, you will find that `NonPreemptingPriority` is `false`, so as default it's disabled.

Output with your current configuration:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-normal     1/1     Running   0          32s
nginx-normal-2   1/1     Running   0          32s
$ kubectl apply -f prio.yaml
pod/nginx-priority created$ kubectl get pods
NAME             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-normal-2   1/1     Running   0          48s
nginx-priority   1/1     Running   0          8s
```

To enable `preemptionPolicy: Never` you need to apply `--feature-gates=NonPreemptingPriority=true` to 3 files:

> /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
>
> /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml
>
> /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml

To check if this `feature-gate` is enabled you can check by using commands:

```
ps aux | grep apiserver | grep feature-gates
ps aux | grep scheduler | grep feature-gates
ps aux | grep controller-manager | grep feature-gates
```

For quite detailed information, why you have to edit thoses files please check [this Github thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/86680).

```
$ sudo su
# cd /etc/kubernetes/manifests/
# ls
etcd.yaml  kube-apiserver.yaml  kube-controller-manager.yaml  kube-scheduler.yaml
```

Use your text editor to add feature gate to those files

```
# vi kube-apiserver.yaml
```

and add `- --feature-gates=NonPreemptingPriority=true` under `spec.containers.command` like in example bellow:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --feature-gates=NonPreemptingPriority=true
    - --advertise-address=10.154.0.31
```

And do the same with 2 other files. After that you can check if this flags were applied.

```
$ ps aux | grep apiserver | grep feature-gates
root     26713 10.4  5.2 565416 402252 ?       Ssl  14:50   0:17 kube-apiserver --feature-gates=NonPreemptingPriority=true --advertise-address=10.154.0.31
```

Now you have redeploy your `PriorityClass`.

```
$ kubectl get priorityclass
NAME                          VALUE        GLOBAL-DEFAULT   AGE
high-priority-no-preemption   1000000      false            12m
system-cluster-critical       2000000000   false            23m
system-node-critical          2000001000   false            23m
$ kubectl delete priorityclass high-priority-no-preemption
priorityclass.scheduling.k8s.io "high-priority-no-preemption" deleted
$ kubectl apply -f class.yaml 
priorityclass.scheduling.k8s.io/high-priority-no-preemption created
```

Last step is to deploy pod with this `PriorityClass`.

**TEST**

```
$ kubectl get po
NAME             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-normal     1/1     Running   0          4m4s
nginx-normal-2   1/1     Running   0          18m
$ kubectl apply -f prio.yaml 
pod/nginx-priority created
$ kubectl get po
NAME             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-normal     1/1     Running   0          5m17s
nginx-normal-2   1/1     Running   0          20m
nginx-priority   0/1     Pending   0          67s
$ kubectl delete po nginx-normal-2
pod "nginx-normal-2" deleted
$ kubectl get po
NAME             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-normal     1/1     Running   0          5m55s
nginx-priority   1/1     Running   0          105s
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After applying the steps you suggested, it works as expected. My only concerns are that a) the docs says "Caution: Critical pods rely on scheduler preemption to be scheduled when a cluster is under resource pressure. For this reason, it is not recommended to disable preemption.", and b) this feature gate is alpha, and "there's an increased risk of bugs and lack of long-term support". Anyway, thank you again.

Comment: It's not recommended, but there are some scenarios which required specific configuration. I'm glad it working for you