# Non-preempting PriorityClass without schedule backof

Tags: kubernetes

I'm working on an application that launches K8S Job (dockerised computer science batchs applications) and I want to prioritizes their launchs.

I don't want to use preemption because all jobs have to be done and I want to be sure that the scheduling order is maintained.

When I read this doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/pod-priority-preemption/#non-preempting-priority-class
It seems that, in non preempting cases, high priority pods can be scheduled after low priority ones if K8S doesn't have the necessary resources at the time.
In case of high priority Jobs are the most demanding, this kind of pods will never be scheduled.

How can I have a control of that decisions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you need to use only Non preemptive refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62135156/19230181) and [Doc](https://tutorialwing.com/preemptive-or-non-preemptive-priority-scheduling/) which helps you in understanding the usage of this non preemptive class.

Comment: Thanks for the links. But I don't find a way to keep the priority order with non preemptive class.

Comment: @SaveriuCIANELLI : I think you can use pod affinity and anti affinity for that refer to this document for more [detailed explanation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/scheduling/pod_affinity.html). This concept is available in kubernetes as well but the explanation is more clear here than in kubernete docs

Comment: It mays be a way to do what I want, yes. I will test that, thank you.

Comment: if you find any solution, Post it as answer for greater community visible.

Comment: Of course, I will test it and I will share my results.